# update panel - dropdown selected index change event not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, checkboxlist

I have one dropdownlist on my page (.aspx) and based on change of selected value i need to bind the data to checkboxlist control which is on the same page. To avoid entire page to be refreshed, i have put the controls in the update panel.

But when i am changes the selection from the dropdown,, it is getting back to the first value itself and the selected index changed even is not getting triggered.
  here is how I have put my controls in the update panel.

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <fieldset>
           <div id="attachmentdiv">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlimportfiles" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlimportfiles_onselectedindexChange"></asp:DropDownList>
           </div>
           <div id="voltagediv">
               <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBoxLstVoltage" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
           </div>
           <asp:Button ID="btnGenerateZBF" runat="server" Text="Generate ZBF" OnClick="GenerateZBF_Click" />
       </fieldset>
   </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlimportfiles" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 </asp:Content>
```

kindly suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: edited. its a aspx page

Comment: You probably did not wrap the databinding of the ddl inside an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                processRequest();
            }
        } I am binding in this way.